# CSS Transition and div inside another div behaves crazy

Tags: html, css

I have two problems with my portfolio section which is not as smooth as I want it to be. Here they are:

1. I wanted my projects to change background-color and show a small plus sign when hovering over them. In the same time I wanted to add a "transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;" but the result is not what I expected. It probbaly happens because my "plus sign" should be located in another div but I didn't know how to make it work. Instead I put it here:

   ```
   .projectshot a .over:hover{
       position: absolute;
       background: url(http://www.iconsea.com/uploadimage/smallsort/4015/4dxtdhpaxqw.png) center center no-repeat rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.6);
       border-radius: 8px;
       height: 150px;
       width: 200px;
       margin: 10px;
   }
   ```

   This is the effect I wanted to achieve: http://bjorsberg.se/
2. The second problem that bothers me is that, if you look really carefully, when you approach each of the projects with the mouse the mouse pointer starts to "dance" and it behaves crazy??? How can I fix that???

Here is my JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8fCMA/2/

```
.plus{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -49px 0 0 -56px;
    background: url(img/plus.png) center center no-repeat;
}
```

I am quite new to web design (4 months since I started learning) and I am clearly not good with positioning div's inside div inside another div... So, please feel free to correct my fiddle if you see any trouble I created. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify the html structure if I were you, as it is not necessary.

e.g.: `projectshot` can look like this:

```
<div class="projectshot">
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">
        <img alt="Sushi" src="...">
    </a>
</div>
```

and you can add the "cover" as `:before` pseudoelement.
Then - in css all you need to do is to add this to the "cover" element:

```
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity .2s;
```

and - on hover - change the opacity to 1:

```
opacity: 1;
```

here's the [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8fCMA/4/)
(I've removed a lot of your html/css code just for demo purposes)

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggestions! It all looks more human friendly now :) What does this property do: content: ''; and what was the problem with "dancing mous pointer"???

Comment: @C.Felipe property `content` is required for pseudo-elements (like `:before` or `:after`) to make them behave more like normal elements. If you remove it - the pseudo-element won't show up. As for the "dancing pointer" - I believe that it was happening because you've attached the `:hover` to the incorrect element...

Comment: Ooops... Just noticed my projects are now not centered and they stick to left side of screen... But I think I should be able to figure this out by myself...

Comment: @C.Felipe that's probably because I've removed your wrappers (divs around projects) and their css. You can add them back. I've just removed them for the demo purposes (so the code is easier to analyse)

Comment: just add this css: .myprojects { text-align: center; }

Comment: It works now. Thanks. I still have to learn a lot but it's much easier with the help of stackoverflow and great people who hang around here!

Answer (score 1):

I've just made some small changes including:

- Moving the hover to the `.projectshot` box.
- Moving `background-position` and `background-repeat` to the non
  hover definition.
- Adding the transitions.

It works for now but you can still remove a lot of code. Even the html can be heavily reduced.
I suggest you to have a look at that too ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8fCMA/3/)).

```
.projectshot{
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.projectshot img{
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 9px 13px rgba(0,0,0,.14);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 9px 13px rgba(0,0,0,.14);
    box-shadow: 0 9px 13px rgba(0,0,0,.14);
}

.projectshot:hover .over{
    background-image: url(http://www.iconsea.com/uploadimage/smallsort/4015/4dxtdhpaxqw.png);
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.6);
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.projectshot:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.over{
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.inner{
    background: rgba(113,122,137,.85);
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}

.plus{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -49px 0 0 -56px;
    background: url(img/plus.png) center center no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Appreciate it! I will go through your updated code and see what changes you have made and what can I learn from it.